# Es posible leer un archivo del servidor* que no sea txt mediante su direccion? Javascript

Tags: javascript, archivo

me encuentro ante la situacion de leer un archivo que se encuentra en mi carpeta Windows, mas exactamente C:\Windows\file.ini.

El archivo NO es un txt pero la idea es poder leer lo que contiene adentro que es texto y guardármelo en una variable.

He estado probando con esta función pero cuando llega a onreadystatechange, tira excepción o directamente no sigue el codigo.

mi codigo:

```
  var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var dir = "C:\\Windows\\Top40.ini";

                rawFile.open("GET",dir, false);
                rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
                        if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
                            var allText = rawFile.responseText;
                        }
                    }
                }
                rawFile.send(null);
```

*Detalle: la idea es NO utilizar < input type='file' > La idea es poder leerlo desde la direccion local*

Es posible realizar esto?

Muchas gracias de antemano

*Correccion: el archivo se lee desde el servidor y no local"

Comment: No se puede. Por cuestiones de seguridad, los navegadores no te van a permitir acceso al sistema de archivos.

Comment: Estas seguro? Porque si yo utilizo <input type='file'> puedo seleccionarlo y leerlo sin problemas. No logro entender por que razon puedo de esta forma y no ingresando el path

Comment: Totalmente seguro, porque una cosa es que el usuario seleccione el archivo en un campo de formulario y otra que quieras acceder a él desde un script.

Comment: Por abundar en la respuesta de @Triby, si desde un navegador fuera posible leer cualquier fichero de windows sin autorización del usuario ¿qué me impide subirme todos tus documentos a mi web sin que lo sepas y usarlos para lo que sea?? ¿u obtener el fichero de contraseñas de tu windows? No hace falta ni comprobarlo, por pura lógica tiene que estar prohibido. Otra cosa es que se trate de un script en node.

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas, ya corregi la publicacion

Answer (score 0):

Resuelto:

```
function leerArchivo() {
const readline = require("readline"),
    fs = require("fs"),
    NOMBRE_ARCHIVO = "C:\\Windows\\Top40.ini";

let lector = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(NOMBRE_ARCHIVO)
});

lector.on("line", linea => {
    console.log("Tenemos una línea:", linea);
});
```

}

Comment: Esto no te va a leer un archivo local, sino del servidor.

Comment: Bien, yo me confundi, la idea era leer del servidor. Muchas gracias por la respuesta